# How to get document share link using OfficeJs in a task pane app?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

Is it currently possible to fetch the share link(both view only or edit) for the opened document? I am wondering if the task of sending the link or adding other users can be automatized from javascript with a predetermined logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [document.getFilePropertiesAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfilepropertiesasync) method.

The result object will contain the file url if one exists.

```
function getFileUrl() {
    //Get the URL of the current file.
    Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(function (asyncResult) {
        var fileUrl = asyncResult.value.url;
        if (fileUrl == "") {
            showMessage("The file hasn't been saved yet. Save the file and try again");
        }
        else {
            showMessage(fileUrl);
        }
    });
}
```